# Change CheckBox state on List item click?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a list and a checkbox in every row of it. 
I want that whenever I click on a row, the checkbox changes its state accordingly.

checkbox.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="" />
```

click listener for my list

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected item no."
            + (position + 1) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    selectedRow = position;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater lif = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = lif.inflate(R.layout.posting_detail_question_row, null);
    }

    if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already voted",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String[] from = {"option", "votes"}; // values to fetch from
        // hashmap
        int[] to = {R.id.option, R.id.votes}; // id's for the view

        SimpleAdapter adp = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                hashList, R.layout.posting_detail_question_row, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adp);
        checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

posting_detail_question_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/poll_border_top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/option"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Answer 1"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/votes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter is a SimpleAdapter:

```
    SimpleAdapter adp = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            hashList, R.layout.posting_detail_question_row, from, to);
    Log.v("MyLog", "after simple adapter");
    setListAdapter(adp);
```

Comment: post here your posting_detail_question_row.xml layout code

Comment: checkout this http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview

Comment: @ P M- Paresh Mayani check it now sir

Comment: @ Lalit Poptani, sir my adapter is simple adapter i guess this thing work for array adapter only

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to use findViewById to get a pointer to your checkbox:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected item no."
                 +(position+1)+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (v != null) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    }
}
```

If you are recieving the onClick event then `v` should never be null but I have put on the appropriate checks.

Comment: @ Merlin this is not working sir, its showing runtime error...i'll rephrase my question again..i want that when i click on any row of the list the checkbox should checked accordingly

Comment: I spotted  asmall mistake it should have been `R.id.Checkbox` but I'm sure you spotted that ... can you look at logcat and see what the error is

Comment: @ Merlin your answer though gave me a gud idea what i m missing i.e the (v!=null) part but still m stuck, if i do according to you my problem got solved but it works on when i click twice because my adapter is created in the else clause and it has missing checkbox... i have updated the code can u look at it and give me some advice..thanks for the answer though..

Comment: I think I see what you mean now ... you should call setListAdapter in onCreate. The when you want to update your data and call notifyDataSetChanged on your listadapter to update the listview.  Your listadapter class should set the value of the checkbox

Comment: @ merlin,i guess the problem is in my simple adapter coz when i vote/click a new adapter is created every time making  my view to null...what do you think??

Comment: read my comment again.  In onCreate() you create your adapter. Then make a change to the underlying data, then call notifyDataSetChanged() method on your adapter.  The adapter will refresh and (if your adapter is correct) update your checkbox

Comment: also make sure that each element in your item layout has these properties :

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"

Answer (score 8):

Inside the onListItemClick do this:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code, you can add this after setting the addapter:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String message = "Item " + position;
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());


        }


    });
```