# android checkbox state does not change

Tags: android

I want to know why my checkbox does not change state from false to true.

I have tried reading from here [how to set check box state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712924/how-to-set-checkbox-to-checked-when-i-click-on-list), and other posts as well but I just haven't figure out whats wrong with my code.

My Java Code:

```
public class OrderActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
public static String orderOne = null;
public static String orderTwo = null;
public static String orderThree = null;
public static String orderFour = null;
public static String orderFive = null;
public static String orderSix = null;

CheckBox chkChickenBreast, chkChickenWings, chkChickenTighs, chkWholeChicken, chkSpicyWings, chkChickenFillet;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    chkChickenBreast = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box_order1);
    chkChickenWings = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box_order2);
    chkChickenTighs = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box_order3);
    chkWholeChicken = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box_order4);
    chkSpicyWings = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box_order5);
    chkChickenFillet = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box_order6);

    Button checkOutOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_confirm_order);
    checkOutOrder.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button backToMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back_to_main);
    backToMain.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick (View view) {
    String[] orderedProduct = new String[6];

    if (view.getId() == R.id.check_box_order1){
        if (chkChickenBreast.isChecked()){
            chkChickenBreast.setChecked(true);
            orderedProduct[0] = "True"; 
        }
        else{
            chkChickenBreast.setChecked(false);
            orderedProduct[0] = "False";
        }
    }               

    if (view.getId() == R.id.button_confirm_order){         
        Intent goToReceipt = new Intent(this, ReceiptActivity.class);

        if (chkChickenWings.isChecked() == true)
            orderedProduct[1] = "True";                 
        else
            orderedProduct[1] = "False";

        if (chkChickenTighs.isChecked() == true)
            orderedProduct[2] = "True";                 
        else
            orderedProduct[2] = "False";

        if (chkWholeChicken.isChecked() == true)
            orderedProduct[3] = "True";                 
        else
            orderedProduct[3] = "False";

        if (chkSpicyWings.isChecked() == true)
            orderedProduct[4] = "True";                 
        else
            orderedProduct[4] = "False";

        if (chkChickenFillet.isChecked() == true)
            orderedProduct[5] = "True";                 
        else
            orderedProduct[5] = "False";

        goToReceipt.putExtra(orderOne, orderedProduct[0]);
        goToReceipt.putExtra(orderTwo, orderedProduct[1]);
        goToReceipt.putExtra(orderThree, orderedProduct[2]);
        goToReceipt.putExtra(orderFour, orderedProduct[3]);
        goToReceipt.putExtra(orderFive, orderedProduct[4]);
        goToReceipt.putExtra(orderSix, orderedProduct[5]);

        startActivity(goToReceipt);
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.button_back_to_main){
        onBackPressed();
        //Intent goToMenu = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(goToMenu);
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

My XML Code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@layout/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_robinsons_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/robinsons_picture_title"
    android:src="@drawable/rsc" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_order_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image_robinsons_logo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_robinsons_logo" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/row_title_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/row_title_price" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/row_title_image" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then it transfer to another activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);

    Intent goToReceipt = getIntent();
    String boolOrderOne = goToReceipt.getStringExtra(OrderActivity.orderOne);

    if (boolOrderOne == "True"){
        TextView orderOne = new TextView(this);
        orderOne.setText(boolOrderOne);
        setContentView(orderOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: first of thing you cannot compare strings using == sign, you have to use equals or equalsIgnoreCase like this boolOrderOne .equalsIgnoreCase("True"). second thing did you initialize orderOne, orderTwo ... they look all nulls

Comment: which line you want to not include?. also make sure to assign unique string values for orderOne, orderTwo , orderThree like orderOne = "OrderOne", orderTwo  = "orderTwo" and so on, these are considered as key to access your data.

Comment: @Moh.Sukhni I have done your instructions with the .equalsIgnoreCase but am still getting a false at the lines `TextView orderOne = new TextView(this);
orderOne.setText(boolOrderOne);
setContentView(orderOne);`

Comment: this line: if (view.getId() == R.id.check_box_order1) is not right, there isn't any onClickListener assign to that check box, please move it to the next if statement like other check boxes, and I think you don't need the if statement //if (view.getId() == R.id.check_box_order1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this form:

This snipped code on oncreat:

```
    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    // get state of checkbox
    boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
    // set state checkbox
    check.setChecked(isChecked);

    // invoked if status change
    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            CheckInActivity.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,
                    "isChecked");
        }
    });

    check.setOnClickListener(isCheckBoxClicked);
```

Methods:

```
public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked, String key) {

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();

}


public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key) {

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sp.getBoolean(key, false);
    return isChecked;

}

// if state of checkbox is true
private OnClickListener isCheckBoxClicked = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if ((check.isChecked())) {

          // Your code if checkbox state is true

        } else {


        }
    }

};
```

Maybe it will help you to try other solution.