# how to enable/disable a check box in a listview while click the list view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-checkbox

i have a custom listview in that, i have text field and check box. when i click on the list view the check box should be enable if it is not enable and vice visa. it is possible in android?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

my listview is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

this is my list in main activity xml

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code? That way you will answer you own question. Post any problems you encounter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set checkbox to checked when i click on list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712924/how-to-set-checkbox-to-checked-when-i-click-on-list)

Answer (score 1):

1) You need an onItemClickListener
2) get the CheckBox
3) set the CheckBox to the opposite if its current status
4) done :)

> ```
> listView.onItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
>        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3){
>             CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
>             checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
>        }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the listener that reacts, when someone clicks on a list-item. 
The View that is given in the method onItemClick is the list-item.

Now you just need to get the CheckBox from the list-item:
`final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);`

And then you can check, if it's checked with isChecked() and set it with setChecked().