# Get child view inside onItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I am facing an issue with onItemClickListener.
I have an list view with row containg an checkbox and i want to set an click on complete row.
When i click on a row the checkbox should be checked or unchecked depends on a condition.

Now the issue is i am not able to get checkbox view inside onItemClickListener so that i can perform further operation.

please check below code:

Adapter getView():

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder vHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        vHolder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_comparelist, null);

        vHolder.chkSelected = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.cbRow);
        vHolder.chkSelected.setId(position);

        convertView.setTag(vHolder);
        vHolder.chkSelected.setTag(listObjects.get(position));

    } else {
        vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        vHolder.chkSelected.setTag(listObjects
                .get(position));

    }

    vHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(listObjects.get(position).getSelected());
    return convertView;
}
```

Activity onItemClick:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbRow);
}
```

In above code it always returns null value.

What is other solution?

EDIT:
I know i can do it inside Adapter by setting OnCheckedChangeListener or onClickListener but i can't do it due to other conditions. So please suggest an solution which can only work with onItemClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've written for onClick is totally true but the origin of returning null from that line is in:

```
vHolder.chkSelected.setId(position);
```

You are changing the value of `R.id.cbRow` to the value of `position` of item!
So when you try to retrieve the view by the value of `R.id.cbRow` **it must** return null.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in getview() function . in adapter class..

```
vHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and add click listener for check box after getview() method

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
            int id = cb.getId();
             // do your code here..

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't want to set listener inside adapter. i need to do it inside onItemClick coz there are some conditions. Is there any solution which can work with onItemClick?

Comment: You can't get the id of any view with onItemclick listener.

Comment: I want to get view not id.

Comment: Try this on listitemclick() listener
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) YourListViewObject.getChildAt(pos).findViewById(R.id.cbRow);

Comment: Same result. returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the Main layout id in which your checkBox is in the getView method and the click of that layout change the selection of checkBox.
For example.
you have in XML

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@linear_layout"
  android:layout_width....  >
  <CheckBox
   android:id="@checkBox"     
   android:layout_width.../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in getView

```
 LinearLayout linLay = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
 CheckBox checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

and

```
linlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClick...{

checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());

});
```

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712924/how-to-set-checkbox-to-checked-when-i-click-on-list?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: see the link at the end of the answer.

Comment: I am not using ListActivity.

Comment: You can also use that in onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long arg3){}. All you need is view.